# Can we send same datapoints in same epoch?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

If we set the steps_per_epoch (in ImageDataGenerator) higher than the total possible batches(total_samples/batch_Size). Will the model revisit the same data points from starting or will it ignore?

Ex:

- *Flattened image shape which will go to Dense layer:* (2000*1)
- *batch size:* 20
- *Total no of batches possible:* 100 (2000/20)
- *steps per epoch:* 1000 (set explicitly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, `steps_per_epoch` is independent of the 'real' epoch (which is number_of_inputs/`batch_size`). Let's use an example similar to what you want to know, with 2000 data points and `batch_size` of 20 (which means 2000/20 = 100 steps for one 'real' epoch):

- If you set `steps_per_epoch` = 1000: Keras asks for a loop of 1000 batches, which basically means 10 'real' epochs (or 10 times of whole data traversal).
- If you set `steps_per_epoch` = 50: Keras asks for a loop of 50 batches, and the remaining 50 batches of one 'real' epoch is visited in the next loop.

Comment: does it mean that if we set steps_per_epoch=1000 in your ex, it is same as using epoch=10 and steps_per_epoch=100?

Comment: If I correctly answer your question, please kindly accept it. Thanks.